# Санкт-Петербургский филиал: заглавная или строчная?

Tags: орфография

> Был создан С(с)анкт-П(п)етербургский филиал.

Answer (score 1):

В прилагательном от Санкт-Петербург "санкт-" обычно отбрасывается. Правда, сейчас это стали регулярно нарушать вслед за властями города. Но если это не официальное название какого-то звена исполнительной власти, то "петербургский филиал" или ещё лучше - "петербуржский". Причин для заглавной нет никаких. В официальных же названиях приходится следовать прихоти чиновников.

Answer (score 0):

В данном контексте речь идет об официальном названии учреждения, предприятия, поэтому должно быть"Санкт-Петербургский филиал". По правилу, при употреблении географического названия в нарицательном значении пишется строчная буква (Северо-Кавказский филиал АН РФ и северокавказская природа), но я не представляю себе слово "филиал" вне  связи с каким-либо официальным названием.

Comment: филиал - это как пример. К примеру, санкт-петербургские предприятия.

Comment: Ну тогда Вы сама уже ответили на свой вопрос в комментарии к моему ответу.